# Postgres interval in total months

Tags: postgresql

I have a Postgres table with interval data, such as:

- 0 month
- 1 month
- 1.5 months
- 9 months
- 1 year

I would like to create a view which displays the values, but in total months (so the correct values in my case would be: 0, 1, 1.5, 9, 12). I have tried using:

```
EXTRACT(MONTHS FROM "MyTable"."Interval"::INTERVAL)
```

However, this yielded incorrect results (0, 1, **1**, 9, **0**).

Is there another function, which would display the expected values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the `extract` function retrieves subfields such as year or hour from date/time values, not the total time you want,but we can construct the result by ourself, as below:

```
postgres=# select * from month_table ;
   month    
------------
 0 month
 1 month
 1.5 months
 9 months
 1 year
 2 years
 1.5 years
(7 rows)

postgres=# select                     
    case when month ~ 'month' then regexp_replace(month,' month.*','')::numeric
         when month ~ 'year' then regexp_replace(month,' year.*','')::numeric * 12 end as months
from 
    month_table;
 months 
--------
      0
      1
    1.5
      9
     12
     24
   18.0
(7 rows)
```

Comment: Thank you, this works great! I am just a little suspicious when using regex. I have an inner (maybe not entirely logical) feeling, that something might go wrong for edge cases... but I guess there is not a built-in or safer way, is there?

Comment: Maybe there is, but I have checked the document about the functions of `time/date` process, do not find,and this is the only way I can think of just right now. If you worry about the edge cases, just check your data carefully, and write a perfect regex that can cover all situations.Good luck ! :)